# Call GET method after code has completed a PUT method

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

I have an app that retrieves users information from the database. They add a user via a modal dialog, once they hit submit this will create a new user, i am trying to figure out how this new user can be displayed straight away without having to do a hard reload. The onSubmit() method creates a new user and within this i have - this.manageUsersComponent.testGet() - which calls out to the method with the get call that retrieves the users information. This line gets called before the create user has finished so the data is not updated straight away.

```js
    public createNewUser(withLogin : boolean, validNewUser : NewUser) : Observable<any> {

        let tokenObservable : Observable<string> = withLogin ?
            this.tokenService.login() :
            new Observable(observer => {
                observer.next('');
                observer.complete();
            });

        return tokenObservable.flatMap(token => {
            if (token.length === 0) {
                token = localStorage.getItem('PlatformApiService.token');
            }

            return this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>(URM_ENDPOINT, this.dummyNewUserRequest, {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                }),
                observe: 'response'});
        });
    }
```

```js
    public getUsers(withLogin : boolean) : Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
        let tokenObservable : Observable<string> = withLogin ?
            this.tokenService.login() :
            new Observable(observer => {
                observer.next('');
                observer.complete();
            });

        return tokenObservable.flatMap(token => {
            if (token.length === 0) {
                token = localStorage.getItem('PlatformApiService.token');
            }

            return this.http.get<HttpResponse<any>>(URM_ENDPOINT, {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                }),
                observe: 'response'});
        });
    }
```

```js
    onSubmit() : void {
        this.formSubmitted = true;

        if (this.addUserForm.valid) {
            let withLogin : boolean = true;
            let unauthorized : number = 401;

            this.createValidUser();

            /**
             * Call the code to Create a new user
             */
            this.addUserService.createNewUser(!withLogin, this.validNewUser)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.status === unauthorized) {
                    return this.addUserService.createNewUser(withLogin, this.validNewUser);
                }})
                .subscribe(
                    response => console.log(response),
                    error => console.log(error));

            this.manageUsersComponent.testGet();

            this.toggleModalDisplay();
            this.addUserForm.reset();

        } else {
            this.userValidator.validate(this.addUserForm, this.formSubmitted);
        }

    }
```

```js
    public testGet() : void {
        // Fill the grid with data
        let withLogin : boolean = true;
        let unauthorized : number = 401;

        this.manageUsersService.getUsers(! withLogin)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.status === unauthorized) {
                    return this.manageUsersService.getUsers(withLogin);
                }})
            .subscribe(
                response => this.fillTable(this.gridConfig, response.body),
                error => console.log(error));
    }
```

Comment: on you `this.addUserService.createNewUser()` function, call to `GET` the new user created in the `response`

Comment: move `this.manageUsersComponent.testGet();` inside the `.subscribe()` block of `this.addUserService.createNewUser` success handler with `response`

Comment: Excellent! This works, thanks for your help @JasonWhite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the onSubmit method so the response calls out to this.manageUsersComponent.testGet()

```js
    onSubmit() : void {
        this.formSubmitted = true;

        if (this.addUserForm.valid) {
            let withLogin : boolean = true;
            let unauthorized : number = 401;

            this.createValidUser();

            /**
             * Call the code to Create a new user
             */
            this.addUserService.createNewUser(!withLogin, this.validNewUser)
            .catch(error => {


                if (error.status === unauthorized) {
                    return this.addUserService.createNewUser(withLogin, this.validNewUser);
                }})
                .subscribe(
                    response => this.manageUsersComponent.testGet(),
                    error => console.log(error));


            this.toggleModalDisplay();
            this.addUserForm.reset();

        } else {
            this.userValidator.validate(this.addUserForm, this.formSubmitted);
        }

    }
```